# C# -> dump all attributes of a class to a dictionary

Tags: c#, syntax

Not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to accomplish this?

given this class:

```
class A
{
    public String B {get;set;}
    public String C {get;set;}
    public String D {get;set;}
}
```

Instantiate A and assign V1,V2,V3 to B,C,D respectively

I would want a Dictionary\Matrix\some other structure containing

```
B:V1
C:V2
D:V3
```

Preferably without using 3rd party libraries

Comment: By attributes, do you mean fields or properties, or both? Because Attributes can also mean something else. Also, what problem are you trying to solve with this solution? Sounds a little [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...

Comment: I'm confused..B/C/D are string properties, why wouldn't you just set them directly? What type of data-type is V1 supposed to be?

Comment: This can be done with reflection, but perhaps the word you're really looking for is 'serialize' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I mean the member variables of a class. The reason I am doing this is because I am using a script component in SSIS to transform some data. The script component gives me a row object. The row object contains an attribute for each column in the input. As part of the processing, I am converting 10 columns to 10 rows (like a simple pivot operation)

Comment: Ok, so it was a basic question. Why the downvote?

Comment: @James the code by Dmitry shows what I wanted to do http://ideone.com/MlL7QN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple example for fields and its values (for public fields):

```
    var a = new A("a", "b", "c");
    var fields = typeof(A).GetFields();
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(fields.Length);
    foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
    {
         dict.Add(fieldInfo.Name, (string)fieldInfo.GetValue(a));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = new A{B = "V1", C = "V2", D = "V3"};

var dictionary = a.GetType()
                  .GetProperties()
                  .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, 
                                prop => prop.GetValue(a));
```

Comment: For some reason, the dictionary doesn't get populated. Any idea why? ideone says Getvalue does not take one argument, my VS does not give any errors though, the dictionary just remains empty http://ideone.com/umLgvr

Answer (score 2):

```
var props = typeof(A).GetProperties();
Dictionary<string, string> output=new Dictionary<string,string>();

foreach(PropertyInfo pi in props)
{
    var name = pi.Name,
    string value= pi.GetValue(this, null) as string;
    output[name]=value;
}
```

Comment: this won't compile, `GetValue` returns `object` not `string`. You probably want to use `ToString`

Comment: why to use `as string`? You probably want to dump integers, datetimes, decimals also in dictionary. In your scenario this values will be `null`

Comment: @llya, too harsh, this is not the main focus!!! we show the idea, not the exact working copy.

Comment: well ok, I ussualy like more robust implementations

Comment: :) I even did not test that, just to give the rough idea.

Comment: sure you didn't test that, because it **doesn't** compiles. For example `A1=new A();`

Answer (score 0):

Note this is only a sample and you should add more defensive code to check that the types of the fields are correct etc...

a simple way using reflection:

```
var a = new A();
.
.  fill in a.B... etc
.
.
Dictionary<String, String> dict = 
               a.GetType()
                .GetFields()
                .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.GetValue(a).ToString())
```

[GetFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx)() returns a [FieldInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx)[] array so you can check for other things first like fields being defined etc.

Comment: `v.GetValue(null)` this will simply throw `TargetException`. Parameter of `GetValue` is the object, from which you want to get the field

Comment: Sorry, sometimes guys get offended when you modify directly their answers by changing the semantics of the answer

Comment: No worries - this is SO and the whole point it community input. But yes there are some sensitive souls around :-)